# Security impact of using constantize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security

I'm currently reviewing some Rails controller. That controller takes user input and based on that user input a new object is created like so:

```
clazz = params[:type].classify.constantize
clazz.new(some_method_which_returns_filtered_params)
```

I'm concerned with the security of this approach. Are there classes in Ruby which the 'new' method could be used with malicious intent?

For example it might be possible to flood the program with new Symbols causing a denial of service (see http://brakemanscanner.org/docs/warning_types/denial_of_service/).

Comment: Without answering your broader question, i'd recommend limiting the values that this code will accept for params[:type], before executing it.  Eg with an if block like `if %w(foos bars bazzes).include?(params[:type])`.  I don't think DOS attacks are a specific problem with doing `classify.constantize` here:  if someone spams your server with requests then that's going do DOS attack you whatever you do in the actual controller.

Comment: You are right this code smells. I would a least check it against a list of allowed class names.

Comment: We're using the above commenters approach in our production code and we haven't noticed anyone "exploiting" it so to speak.

Comment: @limelights - "Nobody's attacked it yet" isn't a measure of security.

Comment: Also, "We haven't noticed anything" doesn't mean that you haven't been attacked!

Comment: This also makes a nice read on expoliting unsafe reflection: http://blog.conviso.com.br/2013/02/exploiting-unsafe-reflection-in.html

Comment: It was very bad phrasing on my part.

Comment: Look further down the code. What is done with the instance? Are any methods used against the instance where a different class might do something unwanted? It is probably cheaper to limit values of `params[:type]` than to even make that check however, and easier to see it has been secured for future developers.

Comment: @MaxWilliams regarding the DOS scale of your comment: you could have a steady number of requests which creates symbols and you might be able to handle this steady number of incoming requests without a glitch, not even remotely looking as a DOS. But your memory might still fail you due to the amassed symbols.

Comment: @rkon - Each request will be handled by one of your worker processes - mongrels, unicorn workers, or whatever.  These will be limited in number - eg to 16.  Each one will garbage collect when it finishes.  The objects you create don't (or shouldn't at least) stick around, accumulating in memory.  DOS attacks will be most effective when they send a request which ties the worker up for as long as possible (so you can get to a point where they are all tied up and there isn't one left to process a genuine request).  Creating a symbol variable takes very little time or memory.

Comment: @MaxWilliams but I thought that the whole issue of symbol DoS attacks is that they are not garbage collected. e.g. Brakeman states the same thing: http://brakemanscanner.org/docs/warning_types/denial_of_service/ Am I missing something?

Comment: @rkon - i see what you mean, sorry.  It's an interesting question - i'm not sure if different web server workers deal with the symbol issue.  I'm not sure how likely it is to be a problem - symbols tend to be redefined rather than making lots of new ones.  I've not heard of anyone having problems with this in real life.

Comment: @Max Williams: It is a real problem, but usually crops up when arbitrary JSON or XML labels are turned into constants. Servers can (and have) failed due to memory load from too many constants. I think that is quite low down security issues list for this code though.

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to never create dynamically-named-from-parameters symbols in your code.  I can't think of any instances where i've ever done this, it's definitely not "railsy".

Comment: Unfortunately I have seen many parameters converted to symbols for a variety of reasons.. White listing is they key :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend limiting the values that this code will accept for params[:type], before executing it. Eg with an if block like

```
if %w(foos bars bazzes).include?(params[:type])
  clazz = params[:type].classify.constantize
  clazz.new(some_method_which_returns_filtered_params)
end
```

I don't think DOS attacks are a specific problem with doing classify.constantize here: if someone spams your server with requests then that's going to DOS attack you whatever you do in the actual controller.

Preventing DOS attacks is hard.  Securing web apps is a massive subject, but in particular you seem to be talking about the area of "sanitizing parameters" here.  Have a look at 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html

I can't resist linking to this classic XKCD strip: http://xkcd.com/327/